# setuid: operation not supported

Tags: go, ubuntu-18.04, setuid

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "syscall"
)

func main() {
        setuidErr := syscall.Setuid(0)
        if setuidErr != nil {
                log.Fatal(setuidErr)
        }
}
```

When I run above code, I get the following error:

> operation not supported
> exit status 1

go version: `1.15.5`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quote from the official documentation

> On Linux Setuid and Setgid only affects the current thread, not the
> process. This does not match what most callers expect so we must
> return an error here rather than letting the caller think that the
> call succeeded.

A possible solution is in this [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d1b1145cace8b968307f9311ff611e4bb810710c)

Comment: That commit was applied to go1.16. See my answer for an explanation of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`syscall.Setuid()` is fixed in go 1.16 on Linux. You can download go 1.16 as follows:

```
$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.16
$ ~/go/bin/go1.16 download
```

Try compiling with:

```
$ ~/go/bin/go1.16 build prog.go
```

You will get a different error: "operation not permitted". This is the kernel preventing trivial privilege escalation...

You want to do one or the other of:

```
$ sudo /sbin/setcap cap_setuid=ep ./prog
```

Or,

```
$ sudo chown root ./prog
$ sudo chmod +s ./prog
```

Now, when you run the command it won't log the error:

```
$ ./prog
$ echo $?
0
```