# How do I escalate/drop root privileges in Go

Tags: linux, macos, go

I'm creating a web service in Go, that potentially binds to a low (<1024) port and needs to access the system SSL certificate and private key files (only accessible to root).

How should I accomplish this?

Is the only way to start the program with root privileges? If the program is started as SUID/SGID privileged, how can I drop privileges? What if it's started via sudo?

Does the same solution work with Linux as well as macOS?

Comment: I would hope there's another way, considering that's all the way from go 1.7. That looks like a hack to me..? Re-running the same program with different context and hoping the program realises upon restart that it's just dropping privileges?

Comment: Fair enough - how about [this](https://play.golang.org/p/dXBizm4xl3) ?

Comment: Isn't that the same solution?

Comment: Upgrade to go 1.16. It is the first version with native support for `syscall.Setuid()` under Linux. I've given a walk through of downloading and using it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443101/5739452). Also the [cap](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap) package let's you manipulate process capabilities to drop privilege acquired through file caps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just grant permission to do the things you need to do without running as root.

For the first part:

```
# allow to bind to low ports even as non-root
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/your/bin
```

will allow you to bind to low ports without root

For accessing system SSL certificates / private key files, you *probably* need to use [`setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)

```
setfacl -Rm u:`whoami`:r /path/to/ssl/certificates
setfacl -Rm -d u:`whoami`:r /path/to/ssl/certificates
```

with the caveat that `setfacl` can be weird with existing permissions

> There are two types of ACLs: access ACLs and default ACLs. An access ACL is the access control list for a specific file or directory. A default ACL can only be associated with a directory; if a file within the directory does not have an access ACL, it uses the rules of the default ACL for the directory. Default ACLs are optional.

and also, you're messing with a pretty critical piece of the system so probably make backups before trying any of the `setfacl` stuff.

Or, on OSX, apparently all ACLs are baked into the `chmod` command, so you could do:

```
chmod +a 'yourusername allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' /path/to/ssl/certificates
```

where you would obviously replace `yourusername` with your actual username, and restrict the permissions you are adding to whatever is necessary.

See https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2011/06/04/acls-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Neither my Ubuntu 21.04 nor my macOS 11.2 have a ``setfacl`` command. What platform was this answer geared towards?

Comment: setfacl should exist on Ubuntu: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/setfacl.1.html, but your right, OSX apparently baked ACLs into chmod so I just updated the answer